Убрать сообщение в Telegram боте
Всем привет!!!
Не могу убрать в Телеграм боте сообщения которые передает пользователь.
Python 3
Aiogram 3
Например:
При команде /start он в ответном сообщении повторяет его. Как можно не показывать?


может стоит документацию прочесть и что делает reply, а что answer

@ClarkDevlin, ответы - в ответы.

@Qwertiy так это комментарий, а не ответ :)

По правилам хорошего тона (и для определения собственно ошибки), на этом сайте следует прикладывать код, который вызывает ошибку или работает не так как ожидается.
В вашем случае, стоит заменить конструкцию типа message.reply() на message.answer(). Первое отвечает на сообщение "ответом", как если свайпнуть сообщение с телефона, а второе просто отправляет сообщение в чат.
